# SOQL to retrieve field of lookup object

Tags: apex, soql

i have a custom object Case_Contacts__c which has lookup to contact object, Case_Contacts__c has field named Contact_Expiry_Date__c. i want to retrieve that field in contact list in controller.

Current Code:

```
List<Contact> ConList = new List<Contact>(
[
    SELECT FirstName, lastName, account.Name, Accountid
    FROM Contact
    WHERE id IN :conIdList
]);

List<Case_Contacts__c> cslist = new List<Case_Contacts__c>();
for(contact c:ConList)
{
    Case_Contacts__c c1 = new Case_Contacts__c();
    c1.Contact__c = c.id;
    cslist.add(c1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Understanding Relationship Names, Custom Objects, and Custom Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm) provides necessary information about how to do it in one soql:

```
List<Contact> conList = [
    select Id, FirstName, LastName, AccountId, Account.Name, (
        select Id, Contact_Expiry_Date__c
        from  Case_Contacts__r
        )
    from Contact
    where id in :conIdList
    ];

for(Contact cont :conList){
    List<Case_Contacts__c> caseContacts = cont.Case_Contacts__r;
    for(Case_Contacts__c caseContact :caseContacts){
        // do something with caseContact.Contact_Expiry_Date__c field
    }
}
```

I can be wrong with child relationship name `Case_Contacts__r`. In first link of this answer you will find how to find correct one.